# button bringing me to user input .html

Tags: javascript, html, button

So I have an HTML web page that has a button and a textbox, so when the user inputs for example "Bread" and hits the button, it will bring them to Bread.html. If they type "Car" and hit the button, it brings them to Car.html. I am really confused on how to do it, so if anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<input id="Login" type="text" value="" /></center>
    <center><button onclick="myFunction()">Login</button></center>
    <center>
        <script>
function myFunction() {
    window.location.href =  document.getElementById("Login")".html";
}
</script>
```

Comment: JavaScript logins are not the best, have you tried server side scripts like PHP for logins?

Answer (score 0):

You’re close. It’s

```
document.getElementById("Login").value + ".html"
```

Your current code isn’t syntactically correct. You need at least an operator before the string literal. And `document.getElementById("Login")` is an `HTMLInputElement`. You need its `value` which is a string.